# Javascript: Why do some variables go in ( ) and some go before keywords?

Tags: javascript

One thing I don't understand is why sometimes you put variables inside of ( ) and sometimes you put them before a keyword with a period.  Is there a rule on this?  Does it have a name?  How do I know and how do I remember?  This is causing some confusion for me. Example below:

```
var myNumber1  = 1234;
var myNumber2  = myNumber.toString();  //variable is before keyword with a period

var myNumber1 = "1234";
var myNumber2 = Number(myNumber);  //variable is after keyword and inside of parenthesis
```

Comment: Variables that go inside `(...)` are parameters for functions while `myVar.method()` is for calling a method or getting a property of an object.

Comment: `Number()` is an object.  You are creating an object with the value contained in `myNumber1` - when you use `myNumber.toString()` you are using the existing definition and converting it to `String` (remember, a `String` is not a `Number` althoug it can represent one in 'letters')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Case 1***

```
Number(myNumber);
```

In short this is just a function, and you are passing in a variable. from the way you asked your question it seems like you understand how this works.

***Case 2***

```
myNumber.toString();
```

In case 2 you are not actually passing in a variable, you are calling a method of that object.

[Dot notation is one of the two ways you can call methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

**[ object ] . [method of that object]**

In javascript almost everything is an object, because of this (like it or not) you inherit the methods of `Number.prototype` in all your numbers.

You can think of .toString() as a method of all number "objects".

If you are interested in learning more about this or how to add more methods your self give [THIS](http://www.sitepoint.com/augmenting-javascript-core-objects-revisited/) a read.

Comment: Thanks Burdock.  So, I can tell it is a function because it starts with a capital letter.  Do methods always start with "to"?  Also, I've heard what's in ( ) as a parameter or an argument.  Is argument the same a parameter?  I'll read the link that you shared.  Thanks for helping a newby.

Comment: Would you like my email? I can help point you in the right direction with a lot of these issues. .. .. .. other wise I suggest asking these as new questions

Answer (score 3):

Those are two different synatxes.

The first one calls a **method** of `myNumber` - a function (`toString()`) that is run on the object.

The second one calls a function (`Number`) with `myNumber` as a **parameter** - that goes in the parentheses.

To learn more about function and method calls, i recommend reading some tutorials. ;) [Here's one by MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions). It's somewhat advanced, but pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

```
myNumber.toString();
```

converts myNumber to a "string of characters". Like "abcd". Is not a number.

As every string is between "",

> ```
> "1234" is a string, not a number.
> ```

So

```
var myNumber2 = Number(myNumber);
```

converts that string to the number `1234` . "Number" is a function to convert that what you passed trought parenthesis into a number.